# Splitting string literal over multiple lines introduces unwanted white space

Tags: c#

```
MessageBox.Show( @"Could not read the Windows Registry.
                 Bailing out...","Registry Error",MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Error);
```

This displays the second line of text with a large about of preceding white space, unless I un-indent the string literal and make my code messy.

Is there a way around this or is it just a detail of how C# works?

Answer (score 1):

When using verbatim strings every white space counts. The following code isn't too ugly.

```
MessageBox.Show( "Could not read the Windows Registry.\n"+
             "Bailing out...","Registry Error",MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Error);
```

Answer (score 1):

The whole point of a verbatim string literal is that it includes the whitespace in the string as well. If you don't want the whitespace you have to not put it in the string.

If you want to split a string across multiple lines without including the whitespace in the string itself you can just split the string itself into multiple strings, each of which are on one line like this:

```
MessageBox.Show( @"Could not read the Windows Registry."+
                 "Bailing out...","Registry Error",MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Error);
```

Comment: It's not a big deal but out of curiosity is this equivalent, or is the string concatenation performed at run-time?

Comment: A quick test in Linqpad suggests that the code `var mystring = "foo"+"Bar";` has a single `ldstr` instruction which loads "fooBar" so the concatenation is done at compile time which makes sense since its a simple optimization. There could conceivably be times when it doesn't, I don't have the patience to look at compiler specs to find out for sure. I'm sure if you asked it as a question you would find that more knowledgeable people than me would find a spec reference (or you might find somebody has already asked).